# Detect when response.redirect has finished?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, response.redirect

I have a form that dynamically generates a PDF based on database data. But I don't want to navigate away from the form whilst the PDF is generated and downloaded. So I am using response.redirect to call the .aspx page that generates the PDF and serves it via stream (Have done for many years) so there may be a better option out there now. However I have found people are logging out before the PDF has been sent to the browser which is causing issues.

Is there a way to detect when the reponse.redirect has finished and the file has been downloaded?

I have tried using postmessage and a listener but this doesn't work. 
I've also tried setting up and EndRequestHandler as below in my main form:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler) ;
```

But this hasn't worked either. The browser is aware as as the tab with the main form has a progress icon in, so there must be a way to intercept the complete event.

Comment: How long does this PDF take to generate? Generally, long running actions that don't require an active HttpContext (such as generating reports) are great examples of code that can be run in a background process. You would deploy a separate application somewhere and have it generate the report, then it can update a status in a database saying the report is completed and/or then call back to the website so that the site can notify the user their download is ready. This eliminates the need for the user to wait while their report is being generated, and allows you to scale the app server as needed.

Comment: You might consider looking into frameworks such as [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) (for a nice UI and system for managing these background jobs), [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) (makes it easy to create Windows services), message bus's such as [Mass Transit](https://masstransit-project.com/) (allow cross application communication), and [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) (realtime notification back to the user when reports have completed) etc.

Comment: Would it be of any use to you to to have the browser present the normal file download dialog? How long does it take to generate the PDF?

Comment: Generally it only takes a few seconds to generate the file. But if the users logs out in the meantime, not all of the information can be collected as housekeeping runs and we end up with an incomplete file.  

We have raised the subject of a background task and even a email service that will fire these reports out once they are generated, but the customer is adamant that the documents must be downloaded there and then. 

Best we can come up with is blocking the UI until the file has downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be accurate like you want it but I do something sort of similar. When the button is clicked, a "Please Wait..." message appear until the file is ready to be downloaded. The way I do it is the client wait for a cookie. When the server is ready to send the file (after processing) it sets a cookie. Even if the cookie was set in a different request, the client still gets the updated value.

Comment: Yeah I have a dialog popped up telling them to wait until the file has downloaded. Just a case is hiding the dialog when the file has completed.

Comment: Cookie may be the way to go

Comment: @TonyLaw If you happen to be using jQuery, there are plugins such as [jquery.fileDownload](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) to help out.